# Remove Byte Order Mark from signed PDF file?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, byte-order-mark

I am using iTextSharp 5.5.1 in order to sign PDF files digitally with a detached signature (obtained from a third party authority). Everything seems to work fine, the file is valid and e.g. Adobe Reader reports no problems, displays the signatures as valid etc.

The problem is that the Java Clients have apparently some problems with those files - the file can be  neither opened nor parsed.
The files have a byte order mark in the header which seems to cause the behavior (\x00EF\x00BB\x00BF).

I could identify the BOM like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
byte[] metadata = reader.Metadata;
// metadata[0], metadata[1], metadata[2] contain the BOM
```

How can I either remove the BOM (without losing the validity of the signature), or force the iTextSharp library not to append these bytes into the files?

Comment: I just checked and iTextSharp doesn't add BOM on its own. Either original PDFs had them before signing, or you add BOM at some point.

Comment: The metadata (which are embedded somewhere in the PDF file) do normally have a BOM and that is ok. *The problem is that the Java Clients have apparently some problems with those files* - which Java Clients?

Comment: @mkl: first, InputStream reads the byte array, then the XMLPullParse (android) throws XmlPullParserException upon parsing the xml. Using a BOMInputStream removes the BOM from the String, so the XMLPullParser can read it in any case. But my requirement is to have the original file without the BOM.

Comment: I have had a quick look at the iTextSharp sources but I couldn't find code adding a BOM. To reproduce your problem, could you share a PDF before and after signing by your iTextSharp app? Furthermore you say you are using iTextSharp 5.3.1; there is no tag for that version in the iTextSharp repository, and there is no 5.3.1 release folder on SourceForge. Thus, it looks like there never has been an official 5.3.1 release or it has been revoked for some reason. You might want to update.

Comment: @mkl: thanks for the hint, it is actually 5.5.1.0, my mistake. Here's the the link to the both files (zipped): http://www.lodi.pl/so/pdfs.zip

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at the files. By the way, you are not only signing but also encrypting the file. Wouldn't it be best to *not encrypt* metadata? That would allow software which is XMP-aware but not PDF-aware to access them. There is an encryption option for not encrypting metadata.

Comment: @lukasz I've offered a bounty but I may have some issues verifying correct answers. Could you have a look as well? I don't have too much time on my hands to do a full code run (yes, I might have thought of that earlier, I just saw a good question and wanted it answered).

Comment: @lukasz I had lost sight of the issue but today I've started looking into it once more. So I've tried to reproduce the issue but couldn't! If I understand you correctly, you sign and encrypt a PDF like your `pdf-unsigned.pdf` sample file (which contains a **Metadata** stream *without* preceding BOM) using iTextSharp and get a result like your `pdf-signed.pdf` sample file (which contains a **Metadata** stream *with* preceding BOM). I'm working with iText for Java, though, so I cannot tell whether there is some issue in the .Net translation or whether your signing code does something wrong.

Comment: @mkl  thank you for your hints. The cause of the problem was the incorrect use of encryption. After correcting that issue, the BOM problem does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first: once a PDF is signed, you shouldn't change any byte of that PDF, because you invalidate the signature if you do.

Second observation: the byte order mark is *not* part of the PDF header (a PDF always starts with `%PDF-1.`). In this context, it is the value of the `begin` attribute in the processing instruction of XMP metadata. I don't know of any Java client that has a problem with that byte sequence anywhere in a file. If they do have a problem with it, there's a problem with that client, not with the file.

The [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is an indication of the presence of UTF-8 characters. In the context of XMP, we have a stream inside the PDF that contains a clear text XML file that can be consumed by software that is not "PDF aware". For instance:

```
2 0 obj
<</Type/Metadata/Subtype/XML/Length 3492>>stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.1.0-jc003">
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
        xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
      dc:format="application/pdf"
      pdf:Keywords="Metadata, iText, PDF"
      pdf:Producer="iTextÂ® 5.5.4-SNAPSHOT Â©2000-2014 iText Group NV (AGPL-version); modified using iTextÂ® 5.5.4-SNAPSHOT Â©2000-2014 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)"
      xmp:CreateDate="2014-11-07T16:36:55+01:00"
      xmp:CreatorTool="My program using iText"
      xmp:ModifyDate="2014-11-07T16:36:56+01:00"
      xmp:MetadataDate="2014-11-07T16:36:56+01:00">
      <dc:description>
        <rdf:Alt>
          <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">This example shows how to add metadata</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
      </dc:description>
      <dc:creator>
        <rdf:Seq>
          <rdf:li>Bruno Lowagie</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Seq>
      </dc:creator>
      <dc:subject>
        <rdf:Bag>
          <rdf:li>Metadata</rdf:li>
          <rdf:li>iText</rdf:li>
          <rdf:li>PDF</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Bag>
      </dc:subject>
      <dc:title>
        <rdf:Alt>
          <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Hello World example</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
      </dc:title>
    </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>                                                            
<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
```

Such non-PDF-aware software will look for the sequence `W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d`, which is a sequence that is unlikely to appear by accident in a data stream.

The `begin` attribute is there to indicate that the characters in the stream use UTF-8 encoding. They are there because it is good practice for them to be there, but they are not mandatory (ISO-16684-1).

You could retrieve the metadata the way you do (`byte[] metadata = reader.Metadata;`), remove the bytes, and change the stream with a `PdfStamper` instance like this:

```
 stamper.XmpMetadata = metadata;
```

After you have changed the metadata, you can sign the PDF.

Note that one aspect of your question surprises me. You write:

```
// metadata[0], metadata[1], metadata[2] contain the BOM
```

It is very strange that the first three bytes of the XMP metadata contain the BOM. XMP metadata is suppose to start with `<?xpacket`. If it doesn't, you are doing the right thing by removing those bytes.

**Caveat:** a PDF can contain XMP metadata at different levels. Right now, you are examining the most common one: document-level metadata. You may encounter PDFs with page-level XMP metadata, with XMP inside an image, etc...

Comment: *Second observation: the byte order mark is not part of the header. It is the value of the begin attribute* - that is how it should be. But if I recall correctly, the OP's sample signed&encrypted file indeed had got a BOM, see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nrj3t.png). (I actually wanted to look into that but lost sight of the issue.)

Comment: I mean: it is not part of the PDF header. The PDF header looks like this: `%PDF-1.`. I'll clarify.

Comment: I've reread the question. It is ambiguous. It says that the BOM is part of the header of the *file*, but the example shows that this is not true: the BOM is found in the XMP metadata. XMP metadata is wrapped inside a stream inside a PDF file.

Comment: Yes, the question isn't all that clear but indeed, the content of the ***Metadata** stream* (decrypted from the signed and encrypted sample file) does start with a BOM. And I am not sure whether that BOM is invalid or merely unnecessary there.

Comment: No answer from lukasz even though he asked a new question over an identical issue... I'll award the bounty even though I cannot fully validate this thorough answer.

Comment: Thanks! I see that the other question has already been answered by mkl

Comment: @owlstead see my comment above to the mkl's hints. Thank you all guys for your help and investigations. Excuse me the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick approach:

First:    save both files un-encrypted.
Second:   remove metadata 0 through 2 before saving the file

There are some considerations however:  does the signing method require a BOM?  Does the encryption method require a BOM?

You will also have to ascertain at what stage the BOM is added before you can determine whether you can/should remove the BOM.

I will have a quick hunt about for my pdf structure docs and see what I can get, however the simplest way would be (untried) load the whole thing as a byte array and simply remove `xEF xBB xBF` from the start of the file, then do any signing/encryption.  However they may add it in again...

I will post an update over the weekend:)